# Can you iterate over hyperparameters in scikit?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

Is there a way to iterate over a Random Forest model so that I create a new model with different hyper-parameters?

i.e.

```
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators= N, max_depth= D)
```

I want to be able to construct a model for each N value ranging from 1 - 25 and D 1 - 5.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than one way to iterate over hyperparameters and train/test models. A simple approach would be:

```
from sklearn import ensemble
from sklearn import model_selection

# generating parameter grid
params = {
    "n_estimators": list(range(1,26)),
    "max_depth": list(range(1,6)),
}
grid = model_selection.ParameterGrid(params)

# iterate over grid and fit/score model with the varying hyperparameters
for param in grid:
    rf_clf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(**param)  # unpacking param which is a dictionary
    rf_clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
    print(rf_clf.score(x_val, y_val), param)
```

An alternate approach that preserves more information and includes cross-validation would be:

```
from sklearn import ensemble
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import model_selection


rf_clf = ensemble.RandomForestRegressor()
params = {
    "n_estimators": list(range(1,26)),
    "max_depth": list(range(1,6)),
}
cv = model_selection.GridSearchCV(
    estimator=rf_clf,
    param_grid=params,
    scoring=metrics.accuracy_score # scorer of choice (optional)
)
# fits model and saves info on each distinct hyperparameter combination using cross-validation
cv.fit(x_train, y_train)  #

# access GridSearchCV object info how you like. For example:
print(cv.best_score_, cv.best_params_)
print(cv.cv_results_)
```